# Why is this text-align center is not working properly with margin 0 auto?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Jsfiddle (increase the window size) https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/5793/
    The text hello world does not align at the center below the image. 
    If you change the image to the larger one https://i.stack.imgur.com/F79On.jpg then you wont see this problem.
    How to solve this issue ?

```
 <div class="img-thumbnail blogborder">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class=bodytitle>Title</div>
  <img class="rounded img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://i.imgur.com/6DcuZx6.jpg">
</div>
</div>
<div class="content">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.col-md-6{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

    .content {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text is aligned center, it is just a matter of aligning your `col-md-6` items, i.e your image i'd suggest change your markup to  the one shown below

`<div class="col-md-6 text-center">
      <div class=bodytitle>Title</div>
      <img class="rounded img-fluid img-thumbnail" 
       src="http://i.imgur.com/VjHAT.jpg">
    </div>`

Add `text-center` to the div will help in aligning the contents to the center. Further reading can be seen at the [bootstrap docs here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/).
Also it would be better to remove the style overrides you got on `col-md-6` and follow `justify-content` and `align-items` since you are already using bootstrap grids